# Bad interaction within USB3 port and HDD docking station

Tags: usb, hard-drive

After 3 years with Ubuntu 12.04, I decided today that it was the right moment to switch to Ubuntu MATE 15.04.

The installation went smoothly, but when I connected my HDD docking station to recover my files, Ubuntu mounted every disk as usual, but after a couple of seconds everything connected to a USB port stopped working for about 5-10 seconds, mouse included (but only USB mouse, the touchpad worked perfectly). During this period the CPU was working furiously in the background, but I wasn't able to see which process was consuming so much power. After that, everything was back to normal, the mouse worked again, but the disks in the docking station became completely invisible to the system. In fact, everything connected to that port was invisible until I rebooted the computer. I'm sure the problem is in the interaction between the docking station and the USB3 because I can connect the docking station to any other USB2 port before and after the crash and I can connect other devices to the USB3 port before the crash.

A few technical details: My laptop is an Acer Aspire TimelineX 4830T, with one USB3 and two USB2 ports. The docking station is a SATA QuickPort Quattro by Sharkoon (http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/node/1825) with 4 HDD, 3 TB each and formatted with ext4.

During the connection through the USB3 port, the disk manager can see the disks in the docking station only for a short time, lsusb waits until the "reboot" of the USB system and gives no output (it works normally otherwise) and the devices appear in /dev only briefly.

I tried to switch on all the disks or just one, before or after the connection, I even tried to use a smaller disk (1 TB), the only change I noticed was in the last try, with a smaller disk it seems the computer requires a longer time to realize there's something wrong, but this time the whole computer was blocked for a few seconds except for the mouse.

I have to say I had the same problem, or something similar, between july and december, with Ubuntu 12.04. It's hard to be more precise, I already had to look through my documents to put these limits. At that time there was a kernel update and after the usual reboot I couldn't connect my docking station. The "solution" was to uninstall the newer kernel and use the old one, so from that moment I haven't dared to install a newer version and after so many months I completely forgot about the problem, until it came back to me.

I hope there are enough details to find a solution, but in case you need more details I'll be happy to post them here.

Edit: as requested I'll leave a copy of `dmesg` here:

```
[  119.659267] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  119.823870] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  119.844253] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[  119.844264] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[  119.844270] usb 2-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[  119.844274] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  119.844278] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1F40FFFFFFFF
[  119.881162] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  119.881483] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[  119.881535] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[  119.881728] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[  119.886041] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[  120.881959] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST3000DM 001-1CH166            PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  120.882641] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  120.882853] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  120.883092] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[  120.883683] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  120.883691] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  120.884270] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  120.884276] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  120.885840] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  121.177771]  sdb: unknown partition table
[  121.179119] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  121.180538] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  121.547759] EXT4-fs (sdb): recovery complete
[  121.547766] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  129.676767] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
[  129.676817] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Assuming host is dying, halting host.
[  129.762256] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Host not halted after 16000 microseconds.
[  129.762262] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Non-responsive xHCI host is not halting.
[  129.762266] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Completing active URBs anyway.
[  129.762286] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  153.621001] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Stopped the command ring failed, maybe the host is dead
[  153.696800] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Host not halted after 16000 microseconds.
[  153.696806] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: Abort command ring failed
[  153.696812] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  153.699429] usb usb1-port1: couldn't allocate usb_device
[  153.699500] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  153.731614] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  153.749228] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  153.749234] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[  153.749237] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  153.749242] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  153.749246] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  153.749249] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  153.749253] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  153.749256] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  154.687510] wlan0: authenticate with 08:96:d7:00:8c:8d
[  154.712853] wlan0: send auth to 08:96:d7:00:8c:8d (try 1/3)
[  154.720156] wlan0: authenticated
[  154.722927] wlan0: associate with 08:96:d7:00:8c:8d (try 1/3)
[  154.745197] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 08:96:d7:00:8c:8d (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=1)
[  154.745356] wlan0: associated
[  154.745641] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DE
[  154.749231] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x8114
[  154.749236] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a country code
[  154.749239] ath: doing EEPROM country->regdmn map search
[  154.749241] ath: country maps to regdmn code: 0x37
[  154.749243] ath: Country alpha2 being used: DE
[  154.749244] ath: Regpair used: 0x37
[  154.749247] ath: regdomain 0x8114 dynamically updated by country IE
[  154.749294] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DE
[  154.749296] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: ETSI
[  154.749298] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  154.749302] cfg80211:   (2400000 KHz - 2483500 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  154.749304] cfg80211:   (5150000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  154.749307] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5350000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  154.749310] cfg80211:   (5470000 KHz - 5725000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2698 mBm), (0 s)
[  154.749313] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
```

And that's what append when I connect the docking station to a USB2 port (I switched on only one HDD every time, always the same):

```
[  694.549927] usb 4-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[  694.644044] usb 4-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[  694.644055] usb 4-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[  694.644062] usb 4-1.1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[  694.644067] usb 4-1.1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[  694.644072] usb 4-1.1: SerialNumber: 1F40FFFFFFFF
[  694.645061] usb-storage 4-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  694.645431] usb-storage 4-1.1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0539: 4000000
[  694.645479] scsi host7: usb-storage 4-1.1:1.0
[  695.643745] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST3000DM 001-1CH166            PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[  695.644616] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  695.645956] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  695.646405] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.72 TiB)
[  695.648324] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  695.648338] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 28 00 00 00
[  695.651575] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[  695.651589] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  695.652694] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  695.949304]  sdb: unknown partition table
[  695.951901] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[  695.954296] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
[  696.417189] EXT4-fs (sdb): recovery complete
[  696.417196] EXT4-fs (sdb): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Comment: Check `dmesg` or /var/log/syslog for errors.

Comment: Done, I copied the relevant output in the question. To be sincere I'm not completely sure the part about wlan is relevant, but it all append at the same time.

Comment: Either there is a bug in your USB3 controller, or in the kernel driver

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought.

Comment: So, does anyone know where the problem is?

Comment: I also have the same problem with a desktop and a hdd dock. I think that if it's attached at boot, the controller doesn't freak out, but if it's plugged in later, it does.

Comment: Yes, I just tried to connect the disks at boot and it works perfectly now. But this is sadly not a solution, I can't reboot the computer every time I need to connect the dock.